# UIScrollView not scrolling after explicitly updating content size from custom class

Tags: swift, autolayout, swift4

I have a custom `UIScrollView` and `XIB`.

```
class DetailsVehicleView: UIScrollView {
   //Created to force the updated content size.
    public func updateContentSize(){
        print("ScrollView  Pre: \( self.contentSize) ")
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero

        for view in self.subviews {
            contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }
        self.contentSize = contentRect.size

        print("ScrollView Post: \( self.contentSize)")
    }
}
```

[image]

I add that to the view of a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UITabBarController`

```
class VehicleInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    var dvv : DetailsVehicleView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let subviewArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DetailsVehicleView", owner: self, options: nil)
        dvv = subviewArray![0] as? DetailsVehicleView
        dvv.frame = self.view.frame

        self.view.addSubview(dvv)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        dvv.updateContentSize()
    }
}
```

[image]

I cannot get the UIScrollView to scroll its content.

Even after I explicitly calculate the value. I can see the scroll bars, but nothing is moving.

```
ScrollView Pre: (0.0, 0.0) 
ScrollView Post: (375.0, 742.0)
```

[image]

***Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?***

Comment: I would try calling `view.setNeedsLayout()` on the parent view and see if that will update the frames of the views...

Comment: Inside your XIB ... Is the top stackView constrained to `Superview.top` or to `Safe Area.top`? And, is the SAVE button constrained to `Superview.bottom` or to `Safe area.bottom`? If they are constrained to `Safe Area`, change the constraint to `Superview`.